# Disable information list in Eclipse on "Refactor" -> "Rename local Variable"

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Due to some reason, my variables in Eclipse do not match convention (first letter upper case). It's not possible to change that.

So when I perform a "Refactor" -> "Rename" on a local Variable, a popup-windows appears:

> "Rename local Variable" - "This name is discouraged. According to
>   convention, names of local variables should start with a lowercase
>   letter."

I click "Continue" and the action is done. But is there a way to disable this check, because it's very exhausting to always confirm with "Continue".

Example:

```
public class Foo{
    private String bar;
}
```

1. Mark the String bar
2. "Refactor" -> "Rename" and type "Bar"

Comment: As a side note don't kill the readability by making first letter as Cap's :(

Comment: I'd love to but I'm not in the position to perform that. And besides that it's historicly grown (taken over from C++) and would be a huge mess to fix.

I would never do that in a new project or if there was a way to bypass it :) - and yes it does kill readability.

Comment: All coding style/conventions are personal/objective. So, I'm with you, @katana0815. `void 我支持你 (){System.out.println ("guess what, this guy use Chinese characters in variable/function name.");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But as earlier said, Don't go against naming conventions.

If still you want ,

Go to `preferences ---> type "refa" ---> click`java`--->`  Uncheck the  `"Rename with out dialog"`  checkbox.

[image]